# How to make pointer variables visible out of a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, scope

How can I view the contents of str_middle in main using pointers and without using a return statement in the function?
I managed to do this with "num" but not for "str_middle".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH_STR  20
#define MAX_LENGTH_MDL  10

void get_middle(char *str_name, char *str_middle, int *num);

int main(void) {
    char str_name_in[MAX_LENGTH_STR + 1];       // Reserved for '\0'
    char str_middle_out[MAX_LENGTH_MDL + 1];    // Reserved for '\0'
    int val_num = 15;

    printf("Enter the string name :");
    scanf("%20s", str_name_in);

    get_middle(str_name_in, str_middle_out, &val_num);

    printf("In main:\n");
    printf("Middle string = %s\n", str_middle_out);
    printf("Numeric Value = %d\n", val_num);

    return 0;
}


void get_middle(char *str_name, char *str_middle, int *num) {
    int length_mld = strlen(str_name) / 2;

    str_middle = str_name + length_mld;
    *num += 1;

    printf("in Func:\n");
    printf("String        = %s\n", str_name);
    printf("Middle string = %s\n", str_middle);
    printf("Numeric Value = %d\n", *num);

}
```

Comment: *Why* don't you want to `return` the pointer value? It's simpler than passing a pointer to a pointer, say `char **midptr`.

Comment: yes @Weather Vane, it would have been much simpler with a return, but I'm following an exercise from a book I'm studying to learn C as a self-apprentice and as it seems I could modify more variables in the function, making them visible also in the main, while the return generally I can only return one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `str_middle_out` to `get_middle()`, it has the address of the output array in main.

So on entrance to `get_middle()`, `str_middle` parameter points to the output array, and if you then just write to it, you'll be able to see it in `main()`.

However, `get_middle()` has this line:

```
str_middle = str_name + length_mld;
```

And now `str_middle` no longer points to the output array defined in `main()`.

Instead, it's pointing to the input array.

So `get_middle()` does its computation and prints its output using the variable used for the computation - `str_middle` (as opposed to the output array defined in `main()`, `str_middle_out`).

But because your computation had lost any connection with the output array defined in `main()`, this array is still empty. That is why you see empty output when `main()` prints `str_middle_out`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
void get_middle(char *str_name, char *str_middle, int *num);
```

should be:

```
void get_middle(char *str_name, char **str_middle, int *num);
```

Bare in mind, that your get_middle just reassigns the pointer inside the function, and have no influence on outside, so what you are really trying to do is to change the value of a pointer outside, and for this, you need to pass the address to that pointer, and change the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your suggestions, I managed to solve the problem using array indexes rather than pointer arithmetic:

```
void get_middle(char *str_name, char *str_middle) {
    char *tmp_str = (str_name + strlen(str_name) / 2);
    int i = 0;

    for(char *p = tmp_str; *p != '\0'; p++)
        str_middle[i++] = *p;
}
```